# CSS style for attachments - icons before text automatically

Tags: html, css, icons, download, attachment

I was wondering how hard it is to make a class for downloads that places an icon right before the text and both text and icon are part of the link to the attached file.  Is there a simple way to do this with CSS?

Comment: Yes, yes there is. What mark-up are you working with?

Comment: I've been using this for ages: http://www.psyked.co.uk/css/auto-matic-link-icons.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all links to downloads are `a` elements, of class-name 'downloadLink':

```
.downloadLink {
    background-image: url(path/to/image.png);
    background-position: 0 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

If those links are of the format:

```
<a href="http://example.com/downloads/document.pdf">document.pdf</a>
<a href="http://example.com/downloads/image.png">image.png</a>
```

Then the css:

```
.downloadLink[href$=pdf] {
    background-image: url(path/to/pdf_background_image.png);
    background-position: 0 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.downloadLink[href$=png] {
    background-image: url(path/to/png_background_image.png);
    background-position: 0 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Will give specific backgrounds to links with a `href` attribute that ends with `pdf` or `png`. This approach is based around CSS3's attribute-selectors, which might reduce cross-browser compatibility but, according to [Quirksmode's compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t31) *not* by much (basically everything above, and including, IE7 should support this (albeit it doesn't specify which of the selectors are supported) in IE or other browsers).

References:

- [attribute-ends-with `$=` selector](http://www.css3.info/preview/attribute-selectors/).